# How to merge two elements before parsing them into JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, element

I'm stuck at the following problem:

I've created a form of which the input gets parsed to JSON at shown to me (later on it'll be transmitted.) 
Now the output from every input field gets in a separate element, see:

```
{
  "hash": "",
  "serviceVersion": "0.5",
  "subject": "yadayada",
  "organisator": "dinitante",
  "roomstyle": [
    "kno"
    "da"
  ]
}
```

The goal is to combine "organisator" and "roomstyle" to "addednote", and replace those two in the output.
I tried various things but couldn't get it to work, this seemed to work but I don't know where to start with changing the output:

```
function join_note()
{
var organisator = document.getElementById('organisator').value;
var roomstyle = document.getElementById('roomstyle').value;
document.getElementById('jointnote').value = roomstyle+organisator;
alert(document.getElementById('jointnote').value);
}
```

This is the js (Babel) that takes the input and displays the output in JSON:

```
const isValidElement = element => {
  return element.name && element.value;
};


const isValidValue = element => {
  return (!['checkbox', 'radio'].includes(element.type) || element.checked);
};


const isCheckbox = element => element.type === 'checkbox';
const isMultiSelect = element => element.options && element.multiple;


const getSelectValues = options => [].reduce.call(options, (values, option) => {
  return option.selected ? values.concat(option.value) : values;
}, []);

const formToJSON_deconstructed = elements => {
  const reducerFunction = (data, element) => {
    data[element.name] = element.value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    return data;
  };
  const reducerInitialValue = {};
  console.log('Initial `data` value:', JSON.stringify(reducerInitialValue));
  const formData = [].reduce.call(elements, reducerFunction, reducerInitialValue);
  return formData;
};
const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {
  if (isValidElement(element) && isValidValue(element)) {
    if (isCheckbox(element)) {
      data[element.name] = (data[element.name] || []).concat(element.value);
    } else if (isMultiSelect(element)) {
      data[element.name] = getSelectValues(element);
    } else {
      data[element.name] = element.value;
    }
  }

  return data;
}, {});
const handleFormSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = formToJSON(form.elements);
  const dataContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('results__display')[0];
  dataContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, "  ");
};
const form = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-form')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

Comment: You could create a [mcve] using the generated JS and the HTML

Comment: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/sprunge1/pen/qXvMmd)

Comment: Click the `<>` and you could post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the form data just before it get sent, and manipulate the json.

```
const json = {
  "hash": "",
  "serviceVersion": "0.5",
  "subject": "yadayada",
  "organisator": "dinitante",
  "roomstyle": [
    "kno"
    "da"
  ]
};

json.addednote = [
  ...json.organisator,
  ...json.roomstyle,
];

delete json.organisator;
delete json.roomstyle;

// You have a ready json object
```

---

Without the spread operator :

```
json.addednote = [
  json.organisator,
];

json.roomstyle.forEach(x => (json.addednote.push(x)));
```